# Raster Operator to use for MaskBlt

Tags: winapi, bitmap, gdi, mask

I'm trying to use the GDI MaskBlt command to draw an image with transparency: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145047(VS.85).aspx

I can't seem to find anything in the documentation about what raster operator to use for the obvious use case: a sort of `MAKEROP4(SRCCOPY, DSTCOPY)` - blitting where the mask is 1, and leaving the destination untouched where the mask is 0. SRCCOPY is a valid ROP, but what should I use in place of my fictional `DSTCOPY` ?

Comment: Turns out my problem wasn't actually with the raster-op I chose, but with my mask bitmap itself

Comment: Which ROP did you use, in the end?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MSDN page "[Ternary Raster Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145130(VS.85).aspx)" explains that the correct value is `0x00AA0029`.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid MaskBlt and use transparency Win32 apis.

Comment: Why? What is the problem with MaskBlt?